# Using a Comparable Interface Java

Tags: java, interface, switch-statement, comparable

I need to implement a comparable interface  into my code so I can compare multiple bits of information from my ArrayList e.g. height. Once I have this working I need to be able to call it in a switch statement. I think I've got the comparable interface bit working however it's showing up an error message when I try to call it in the switch statement. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is/how I can fix it? I've just attached the relevant code but please say if I need to attach more.

**Comparable Interface**

```
public class Superhero implements Comparable<Superhero> {

public int compareTo(Superhero other) {
        return Integer.compare(this.height, other.height);
    }
```

**Switch Statement**

```
        case 5:

           System.out.println(sortMenu());
           int val = input.nextInt();
           switch (val) {
                //HEIGHT
                case 6:
                    System.out.println(Superhero.compareTo());
            }

            break;
```

EDIT

error message when I run the code added below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
at heros.java.Heros.main(Heros.java:54)
Java Result: 1
```

compiler error message:

```
method compareTo in class Superhero cannot be applied to given types;
require: Superhero
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: what is the error message or stackrace your getting when you run it?

Comment: `Superhero.compareTo()` ? What are you trying to compare here?

Comment: @iHappyk just added the error message

Comment: you need to pass one more object of Superhero as parameter to the compareTo method

Comment: Don't run uncompilable code. Give us the compiler's error message in this type of situation.

Comment: @Eran I'm trying to compare the heights of the superheros

Comment: @rosie_hyde But you should call `compareTo` on an instance of `Superhero` and pass another `Superhero` to the method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've attached the compilers error message

Comment: @iHappyk could you explain this to me, I'm not quite sure what you mean by this?

Comment: And it tells you **exactly** what you're doing wrong -- you're calling the method with the wrong arguments. Lesson: don't ignore the messages that the compiler gives you as they'll usually tell you exactly what is wrong and where.

Comment: @rosie_hyde Added the answer below please check

Comment: @rosie_hyde you should accept an answer below. There are several correct answers now. It's also a kindness to upvote any others that are also correct and useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly identified that your problem is in this snippet of code:

```
case 5:
    System.out.println(sortMenu());
    int val = input.nextInt();
    switch (val) {
        //HEIGHT
        case 6:
             System.out.println(Superhero.compareTo());
    }
    break;
```

It's on this line:

```
System.out.println(Superhero.compareTo());
```

In this expression:

```
Superhero.compareTo()
```

**Superhero** looks like a variable here (variables should start with lowercase, so that is confusing) and you need to supply another **Superhero** object to it as follows:

```
Superhero anotherSuperhero = new Superhero();
System.out.println(Superhero.compareTo(anotherSuperhero));
```

Answer (score 1):

> actual and formal argument lists differ in length

The error clearly says that you need to pass required argument(object of `Superhero`) to make it work in below code.

```
System.out.println(Superhero.compareTo());
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see below, the [compareTo()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Comparable.java#Comparable.compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29) method from the Comparable interface takes a generic as parameter. [compareTo()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Comparable.java#Comparable.compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29) without parameter does not exist.

```
public int compareTo(T o)
```

---

### Solution

```
Superhero.compareTo(otherSuperheroObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass one more object of Superhero as parameter to the compareTo method.

```
Superhero h1 = new Superhero();
Superhero h2 = new Superhero();
```

you need to call compareTo method like below

h1.compareTo(h2);

Comment: **compareTo** doesn't return **height**.

Answer (score 0):

You are using compareTo like a static method of Superhero class. You have to call it on one Superhero instance to compare it with another instance.

```
Superhero superhero1 = new Superhero();
superhero1.setHeight(10);
Superhero superhero2 = new Superhero();
superhero2.setHeight(20);

int compareResult = superhero1.compareTo(superhero2);
```